# How could you do this query in laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5.1

the goal is to get a list of posts with date of last comment

```
 select
    `posts`.*,
    `follow_posts`.`follower_id` as `pivot_follower_id`,
    `follow_posts`.`post_id` as `pivot_post_id`,
    `follow_posts`.`created_at` as `pivot_created_at`,
    `follow_posts`.`updated_at` as `pivot_updated_at`, (select max(updated_at) from `comments` where `commentable_id` = `posts`.`id`) as `comentario`
from 
    `posts`
inner join 
    `follow_posts` on `posts`.`id` = `follow_posts`.`post_id`
where 
    `follow_posts`.`follower_id` = '1' 
order by 
    `comentario` desc
```

Comment: Do you have Eloquent models for you `Posts` and `Followers`? If so you can just set a `many-to-many`  relationship up. http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Yes, I have the necessary models and the relationship , but do not know how to relate the 'Post' with the last comment of the table 'comments' .

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, Have you got your `posts`-`comments` relationship set up as a `hasMany`  or a `morphMany`? As well if you are going to be using Eloquent for this query it might be better to put all of the necessary relationship methods in to your question as it's a bit misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a Model called `Post` related to table `posts`:

```
use App\Post;
...
$posts = Post::innerJoin('follow_posts', 'posts.id', '=', 'follow_posts.post_id')
             ->where('follow_posts.follower_id', '=', '1')
             ->orderBy('comentario', 'desc')
             ->select([
                 'follow_posts.follower_id as pivot_follower_id',
                 'follow_posts.post_id as pivot_post_id',
                 'follow_posts.created_at as pivot_created_at',
                 'follow_posts.updated_at as pivot_updated_at',
             ])->selectRaw('
                 (select max(updated_at) 
                  from comments
                  where commentable_id = posts.id) as comentario')
             ->get();
```

I think you have to specify all columns you want to select from table `posts`. Event if you don't need to do this, it's faster(you probably don't need all of them) and you know exactly what you are working on.

If you don't want to build this as mentioned above you can always use

```
$posts = DB::select('SELECT ...');
```